# How to get POST request values in Django Views?

Tags: python, django, post, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to make a signup form via html/django so I have 3 input boxes for the user to put in the email, username, and password that then sends them via POST to /adduser

```
<form action="/OmniCloud_App/adduser" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></br>
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength=25 /></br>
  Password: <input type="password" maxlength=30 /></br>
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <input type="reset">
</form>
```

adducer creates a new User and saves it to the DB:

```
def adduser(request, email, username, password):
    u = User(email=email, username=username, password=password)
    u.save()
    return render_to_response('adduser.html', {'email':email, 'username':username, 'password':password})
```

but when I click submit on /signup, it complains that I am only giving it 1 parameter when 3 were expected. How should I pass the email,username, and password fields from signup.html to the username function (located at /username)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/), you'll see that the view function expects parts of the URL itself as arguments. If you read [part 4 of the same tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/), you'll see that POST parameters come in via `request.POST`. Further in the documentation, you'll learn that you can write Form classes that handle both the generation and validation of HTML forms.

Comment: Okay, so I used that, but now it says that password isn't part of the POST request, but it does appear to have email, username, and something funky called csrfmiddlewaretoken. Why wouldn't it send the password field of the form as well?

Comment: Because you forgot to give it a name. Which is yet another reason to use Django forms.

Comment: You're too good. I will look into the form class, just wanted to make it through the damn tutorial first haha. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

they will be in `request.POST`, which you can query like you would a `dict`

```
email = request.POST.get('email')
username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is ["mapping"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: But how to populate POST?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you submit the `POST` request values in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="meat" value="beef" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/how-to-get-post-request-values-in-django/77136495#77136495) explains it more:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    print(request.POST['fruits']) # apple
    print(request.POST.get('meat')) # beef
    print(request.POST.get('fish')) # None
    print(request.POST.get('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.POST.getlist('fruits')) # ['apple']
    print(request.POST.getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.POST.getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.POST._getlist('meat')) # ['beef']
    print(request.POST._getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.POST._getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(list(request.POST.keys())) # ['csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'fruits', 'meat']
    print(list(request.POST.values())) # ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS', 'apple', 'beef']
    print(list(request.POST.items())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'), ('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.POST.lists())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS']), ('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.POST.dict()) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.POST)) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'], 'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}

    return render(request, 'test.html')
```