# How to get POST request values in Django?

Tags: python, django, post, http-post, httprequest

I have the following django template (http://IP/admin/start/ is assigned to a hypothetical view called view):

```
{% for source in sources %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ source }}</td>

    <td>
    <form action="/admin/start/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ source.title }}">
      <input type="submit" value="Start" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
    </td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`sources` is the `objects.all()` of a Django model being referenced in the view. Whenever a "Start" submit input is clicked, I want the "start" view to use the `{{ source.title}}` data in a function before returning a rendered page. How do I gather information POSTed (in this case, in the hidden input) into Python variables?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Read about request objects that your views receive:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects

Also your hidden field needs a reliable name and then a value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ source.title }}">
```

Then in a view:

```
request.POST.get("title", "")
```

Comment: I use Django Forms where I don't have an independent `input` and just a `{{ form }}` and my form has only one text input (charfield). how can I access its data?

Comment: @Nitwit the `name` attribute will be the name of the property you assigned the charfield to. If your not 100% press F12 while in the browser with the form loaded and select the input element to see what Django gave the name attribute.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to do something on the front end you can respond to the onsubmit event of your form.  If you are just posting to admin/start you can access post variables in your view through the request object. request.POST which is a dictionary of post variables

Comment: The other answer helped me with a problem I was going to ask you (definitions of name/value html selectors) before I asked it, so I'll go ahead and mark that one accepted. Thanks for your help though. :)

Answer (score 5):

For django forms you can do this;

```
form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST) #getting the whole data from the user.
user = form.save() #saving the details obtained from the user.
username = user.cleaned_data.get("username") #where "username" in parenthesis is the name of the Charfield (the variale name i.e, username = forms.Charfield(max_length=64))
```

Comment: UserLoginForm in the answer is the name of the form

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
request.POST['title']
```

it will easily fetch the data with that title.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you submit the `POST` request values in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="meat" value="beef" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581114/how-to-get-a-post-request-values-list-in-django/77143591#77143591) explains how to get a `POST` request values' list in Django and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129172#77129172) explains how to get `GET` request values in Django:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    print(request.POST['fruits']) # apple
    print(request.POST.get('meat')) # beef
    print(request.POST.get('fish')) # None
    print(request.POST.get('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.POST.getlist('fruits')) # ['apple']
    print(request.POST.getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.POST.getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.POST._getlist('meat')) # ['beef']
    print(request.POST._getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.POST._getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(list(request.POST.keys())) # ['csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'fruits', 'meat']
    print(list(request.POST.values())) # ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS', 'apple', 'beef']
    print(list(request.POST.items())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'), ('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.POST.lists())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS']), ('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.POST.dict()) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.POST)) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'], 'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}

    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values in `test.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "test.html" #}

{{ request.POST.fruits }} {# apple #}
{{ request.POST.meat }} {# beef #}
{{ request.POST.dict }} {# {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'Vzjk89LPweM4loDWTb9gFNHlRQNJRMNwzQWsiUaWNhgBOr8aLfZyPjHobgqFJimk', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
```