# How to get GET and POST request values in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, post, django-templates, get

I want to be able to access a bit of information that someone places in a GET variable right in the template of a page (HTML escaped, of course.) How would I go about doing this? I know you can grab this information with views, but in this case, I'd rather handle it HTML side.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear. How do you want to handle the GET and POST in your template. I am asking this because GET and POST are methods through which variables are sent to views and within the template.

Comment: I'm using direct_to_template, and want to put one of the variables in a hidden value in a form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass that information from view to the template just as passing another variable. When you are rendering your template, just add a variable and pass `request.GET` QueryDict. You will be able to access all of the GET parameters within your template.

### EDIT

`direct_to_template` automatically includes `RequestContext(request)` so you will be able to use all of your context instances in your settings. Please add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py. Afterwards, you will be able to use access Django's HttpRequest by `{{ request }}` in your template. Example settings, urls, and template are below:

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (                                         
    'django.core.context_processors.request',

     # these are the default values from django. I am not sure whether they
     # are overritten when setting this variable, so I am including them             "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",                  
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",                         
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",                          
    "django.core.context_processors.media",                         
    "django.core.context_processors.static",                        
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",                            
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"           
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',                      

    url(r'^about/$', 'direct_to_template', {'template':                    
        'about.html'}),
)
```

**about.html**

```
Your request is: <br /><br />                                                                                                                                                                                           

{{ request.GET }}
```

Please also see the documentation about the topic:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Comment: My hope is to avoid using a view in this instance. Is there no way to grab the variables without passing them explicitly from a view? I'm using direct_to_template, and want to put one of the variables in a hidden value in a form.

Comment: Have you tried in your view to access the information you want with `request.get`? Accordingly to django, `direct_to_template` adds RequestContext by default, which should enable you to access `request` parameters in your template.

Comment: Could you give an example and place it in the answer? It sounds just like what I want.

Comment: Here it is. Edited the answer. You can check it.

Comment: You'll also need `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` to avoid the KeyError on the admin panel.

Answer (score 3):

In new Django you can use directly in template like:

if post request with request.POST['name'] in view.py, in template you can use:

```
{{request.POST.name}}
```

if get request in template you can use:

```
{{request.GET.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you submit the `GET` request values in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="meat" value="beef" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `GET` request values in `test.html` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129172#77129172) explains how to get `GET` request values in Django:

```html
{# "test.html" #}

{{ request.GET.fruits }} {# apple #}
{{ request.GET.meat }} {# beef #}
{{ request.GET.dict }} {# {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }} {# fruits=apple&meat=beef #}
```

And, if you submit the `POST` request values in `index.html` as shown below. *`method="post"` needs [csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-csrf_token) tag in `<form></form>` otherwise there is error:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="meat" value="beef" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values in `test.html` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/how-to-get-post-request-values-in-django/77136495#77136495) explains how to get `POST` request values in Django:

```html
{# "test.html" #}

{{ request.POST.fruits }} {# apple #}
{{ request.POST.meat }} {# beef #}
{{ request.POST.dict }} {# {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'Vzjk89LPweM4loDWTb9gFNHlRQNJRMNwzQWsiUaWNhgBOr8aLfZyPjHobgqFJimk', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
```