# How to get all POST request values in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, http-post

Is there any way get all the form names from a request in Django?

```
<input type="text" name="getrow">
```

Html request

```
def demoform(request):
    if request.method=="POST"
       inputtxt=request.POST.get("getrow")
       return HttpResponse(...)
```

in the above I can get only from the `name` I know, what I need is to get all names of the django request and later parse it and get data.

Comment: `request.POST.keys()`?

Comment: can you refer any example of it ?

Comment: What are you using it for? most post data is used for a form and there are better ways of handling that.

Comment: I want to send data from from to django and the `<input type="text">`  I want to send are created according to the user input.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try use this:

```
def demoform(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        inputtxt=request.POST['getrow']
        return HttpResponse(...)
```

But if you need print a dynamic POST data, for example send the slug of many products, (i made it 2 days ago "April 22, 2018") you need try this:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    print('Key: %s' % (key) ) 
    # print(f'Key: {key}') in Python >= 3.7
    print('Value %s' % (value) )
    # print(f'Value: {value}') in Python >= 3.7
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: @ChandraPavan see again the solution

Answer (score 16):

To display POST values in django you can do:

```
print(list(request.POST.items()))
```

You can also also use `dict()`

```
print(dict(request.POST.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all the above answers of our friends have cleared everything about how to get all post data. Again I can explain for you that first check the request method, then you can print out on console as well.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
           print(request.POST)
```

BTW, request.POST returns a dictionary structured data, so if you know the requested data already then you can pass within the POST to retrieve.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
           print(request.POST['username'])
```

but, if you want to work on the requested I mean you want to filter out the desired data then just create a dictionary object then work on that.

```
post_data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
           post_data = request.POST
print(post_data['username'])
```

if you don't know the key, then you can just filter out through retrieving all keys from dictionary.

```
for key, value in post_data.items():
         if key == 'username':
                   print(value)
```

that's it, hope I answered you well.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you submit the `POST` request values in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="meat" value="beef" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get all the `POST` request values in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/how-to-get-post-request-values-in-django/77136495#77136495) explains how to get `POST` request values in Django:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    print(list(request.POST.items())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'), ('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.POST.lists())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS']), ('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.POST.dict()) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.POST)) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b0EQnFlWoAp4pUrmsFxas43DYYTr7k04PhhYxqK3FDTBSXWAkJnsCA3GiownZQzS'], 'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}

    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

Then, you can get all the `POST` request values in `test.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "test.html" #}

{{ request.POST.dict }} {# {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'Vzjk89LPweM4loDWTb9gFNHlRQNJRMNwzQWsiUaWNhgBOr8aLfZyPjHobgqFJimk', 'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
```