# Django : Displays "No Value " When trying to fetch checked checkbox without submit using AJAX

Tags: django, ajax

i wrote a program using django to retrieve all checked checkbox without submit button by using AJAX , it is not throwing any error , but it displays "NO Value " . Can anyone check and tell me what is the mistake i did .

AJAX :

```
<script>
                  $('.form-check-input').change(function(){ // checkbox1 change event
                  var checked_lists = [];
                  $(".form-check-input:checked").each(function() {
                      checked_list.push(this.value);
                  });
                  var formdata = new FormData();
                  $.ajax({
                          formdata.append('checked_list',checked_list)
                          formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',$('input[type=hidden]').val());
                          $.ajax({
                              url:"secondtableonDashboard", //replace with you url
                              method:'POST',
                              data:formdata,
                              enctype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                              processData:false,
                              contentType:false,
                              success:function(data){

                                 alert("Display return data"+data)
                              },
                              error:function(error){
                                  alert(error.error)
                              }
                          });
                  });
                  });
            </script>
```

Views.py

```
def secondtableonDashboard(request):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=ABC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                          'Database=WebstartUI;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from CustomerServer")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    if request.method=='POST':
       user_list = request.getlist('checked_list')
       print(user_list)
    else:
       print("No Values")
```

html :

```
<td>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
 <input class="form-check-input" name="Servers[]" value="{{datas.ServerName}}" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
</div>
</td>
```

So here i use my views.py, same function to keep data in checkbox and to get POST values.

UI:
[image: Ima]

Comment: Hi, why do you have two `$.ajax({` ?

Comment: Is one enough , am not so good at AJAX @Swati

Comment: remove that outer `$.ajax({..` and try again .

Comment: it's not working i tried now @Swati

Comment: what doesn't work  are you seeing any error ? did you print `formdata` does it has right value ? Also , try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814805/10606400) to see what all data are coming to server .

Comment: Your terminal shows `GET` request it should be `POST` according to your code ?

Comment: how to change that @Swati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230473/discussion-between-swati-and-aurora-eugene).