# Printing POST Request Value in Django

Tags: python, django, post

I'm beginning to learn web development with Django and I've run into a problem, I have a form :

```
from django import forms
from .models import film

class searchFilm(forms.Form):
    FilmName = forms.Field()
```

and in my views file I try to print the search term:

```
print request.POST["FilmName"]
```

but I get the error:

```
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'FilmName'"
```

if I just print the whole thing I get the output:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'************'], u'FilmName': [u'hellowe']}>
```

And I'm not sure why, how do I just print the search term?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request

Comment: I've looked through those comments and I'm still stuck, if I loop through the POST dictionary to print all keys, I get 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' and 'FilmName', so surely doing print request.POST["FilmName"] should print the text entered into the field?

Comment: Django raises `MultiValueDictKeyError` if you try to access values which are not in the POST dictionary. You should use `print request.POST.get('FilmName', None)` It will print `None` if `'FilmName'` is not in POST dict.

Comment: Can you show the complete view?

Comment: If you're using a form, you should be accessing `form.cleaned_data` rather than the raw POST, anyway.