# How to access what was filled in an HTML element from a POST request? django

Tags: django, post, django-templates, django-views

In my Django application, I need to access what the user filled in the City text field.

This is the city text field from the template:

```
<label class="reglabel">City: </label><br>
{{ profile_form.city|add_class:"input-md textfields" | attr:"placeholder: Search Cities..."|attr:"id:searchBoxGlow" | attr:"name: cityname" }}
{{ profile_form.city.errors }}<br>
```

In my View.py file I try to access the value using the name attribute I added to the template:

```
print request.POST.get("cityname", "")
```

I followed advice from this question:

[Django - taking values from POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request)

This is the form, at this stage I just want to pull the text the user fills so I can turn it into a city instance and save the form.

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profilepic', 'city', 'hobbies', 'languages')
```

However, it prints blank instead of what the user filled in the City text field.

Comment: Are you sure you're making a POST request? Try printing `request.POST` to see what is contained there.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I print request.POST I receive the following:

```
<QueryDict: {u'city': [u'London, United Kingdom'], u'first_name': [u'seifautocomplete'], u'last_name': [u'Elmughrabi'], u'languages': [u'263'], u'hobbies': [u'2110'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'aPBSrZgfhHx03xPKF5xc5NtLrPL1r1Bc'], u'profilepic': [u'']}>
```

In order to pull city I need to use the key which is: 'city' instead of using HTML element name attribute like I did in the question body.

This is what I need to do:

```
print request.POST.get("city", "")
```

The issue is resolved.