# request.POST from Django with Javascript submit form

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to get your help on my issue. Usually, when I submit a `POST request` in `Django` with a submit button, I take the button name like this :

```
<button id="document-button" type="submit" name="UpdateDocument">Submit</button>
```

And in my view :

```
if "UpdateDocument" in request.POST:
    ... do something
```

But in my code, I need to submit my form with Javascript `onchange` method. Hence, I don't have any button to submit my form :

```
<form id="select-animal-form" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="name">Select Animal</span></legend>
      {{ form.animal_list }}
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
  $('#select-animal-form').on('change', function(){
    $(this).submit();
  });
</script>
```

I would like to pick up the submit `request.POST` for this form. I wrote this :

```
if request.POST and not "UpdateDocument" in request.POST:
    ... do something
```

But even buttons `Next` or `Previous` in my pagination are called in this part. I just want to call in this part the submit form.

How I can do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - taking values from POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in my case, I didn't have any HTML submit button. All is done with Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden input inside the form as below and check if that exist in `request.POST`

```
<form id="select-animal-form" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="name">Select Animal</span></legend>
      {{ form.animal_list }}
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitButton">
</form>

<script>
  $('#select-animal-form').on('change', function(){
    $(this).submit();
  });
</script>
```

in view

```
if "submitButton" in request.POST:
```