# How to send data to a page in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-models

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="sample">
<option>.....</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Python file

```
def reqData(request):
    # overhere i want the data selected by the user, and then will iterate that data through my DB to fetch the desired results
```

The web page is going to run on a GET request, but the data that is needed is coming from a POST request, so how to get the data from the select tag.

Comment: Do yo have a submit button in your form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - taking values from POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes it does have a button

Comment: @PrathamDave: a button of `type="submit"`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not much, because i have tried that way

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is what i have done

`<form action="{% url 'final' %}>
<select></select>
<button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>`

Comment: I am confused for how to get post data on a get request page