# How can I use request.method in a django python file?

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I'm trying to get the data from a POST but I can't use the 'request' it says "NameError: name 'request' is not defined". I tried using 'import request' it says that 'No module named 'request''. This code is from my views.py that working well. Is it possible to use this also in a python file? or there is another way? I also add request to the def update_extend_traces_traceselect(request).

in my graph.py

```
 def update_extend_traces_traceselect(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        value = post_data.get('data')
        print(value)
```

Comment: If the `update_extend_traces_traceselect` is a handler, then you should pass a request parameter. `def update_extend_traces_traceselect(request):`

Comment: request is passed to the view function. If update_extend_traces_traceselect is configured as view handler in your urls.py, then you should define it as `def update_extend_traces_traceselect(request)`

Comment: You can't pass request as an argument to every function in django. It has to be a view function. If it is a regular function it will not recognize request.

Comment: @Aman it there another way to get that data in a regular function?

Comment: @CasonMercadejas you can call regular function inside your view. that way you can pass current request

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `request` to the function parameter.

```
def update_extend_traces_traceselect(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        value = post_data.get('data')
        print(value)
```

Read more about the [Django request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/) and how to use it in [function-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/).

Comment: @CasonMercadejas If it's printing that, then you're not POSTing a JSON object that has a `None` key.

Comment: Your question was about using request in a function based view. Now it seems that you have another question related to reading POST data. I think this should be a new question. You can also read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336580/4151233